# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'. - Gradle Task assemble

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

so I was trying to run my flutter project and then I got this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Programmin\Flutter\app_with_firebase\build\app\intermediates\merged_java_res\debug\out.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to do : `File > Invalidate Chaches/Restart` in Android studio, but it won't solve the problem. I also tried to do `flutter clean`, then `flutter run`, but It still shows me the same error.

I have no idea what to do now, any help is appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: I've been experiencing this error for some months now, and it's maddening. As an immediate fix, you can (on Windows) run `taskkill /F /IM java.exe` to kill all Java processes that will release a file lock before running `flutter run`, but it's not guaranteed to work each time. Something (Gradle daemon? VS Code Flutter extension?) is holding a lock, I just still haven't figured out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit more digging with `SysInternals` and `jps` and it turns out that the  Kotlin Language Server wasn't releasing the lock on the build folder. For me, uninstalling the VS Code fwcd Kotlin extension (and replacing with a different Kotlin language extension, if required) was enough to fix the issue.

On Android Studio, all I can suggest is disabling/uninstalling the Kotlin plugin and seeing if that fixes it for you.